# Norm of Weyl tensor on homogeneous riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

A connected riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ is called homogeneous
if the group of isometries of $(M, g)$ is transitive on $M$.
Why is the norm of Weyl tensor constant on a homogeneous $M$?

Comment: The main point in my opinion is that isometries preserve the curvature.